# How to export a list to web page text box using selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My work here is to get data from google sheets and put those values in the webpage text box - using python

In my google sheet, I have 450 rows which are comma-separated values.
I need put all the 450 rows data into the webpage text box using selenium send.key().

```
##getting data from google sheets.

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('json',scope)

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

workbook = client.open_by_url("https://docs.googlesheet") # using google sheet here
sheet1 = workbook.worksheet("Sheet1")
##converted sheet1 data into a dataframe called dera.
dera = gd.get_as_dataframe(sheet1, evaluate_formulas=True, skiprows=0, has_header=True)
##from dera dataframe reading 'names' column and removing null values.
del = dera[['names']].dropna()
##Converted my dataframe into list- I have read it will be easy to put list(z) values in send keys
z = del['names'].values.tolist()

Selenium code:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/naveenbabudadla/Documents/automation/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://google.com/") # using google.com as example

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Maximum 5000 names'] /..//textarea").send_keys(z) ## got stuck here.
time.sleep(2)
```

---

not able to define "z" to selenium send keys correctly.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you add error you are getting?

Comment: KeyError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-9194104ac257> in <module>
     12 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Manual']")
     13 time.sleep(2)
---> 14 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Maximum 5000 UUIDs'] /..//textarea").send_keys(z)
     15 time.sleep(2)
     16 ##select =
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    476 
    477     self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
--> 478     {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    479      'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

Comment: `KeyError` indicates that you are trying to extract nonexisting element from some collection, eg. nonexisting key from dict. What you posted doesn't look like legit stacktrace, did you mix error with your code?

Comment: I have added the script here. This may help you understand my question correctly

Comment: Your code is incomplete but I can see some room for improvement here. In line 2 you assign something to `sh` then in next line you use `sh1`, if you meant the same variable then correct it. Then in line 4 it seems you are assigning something to variable named `del` which is a build in keyword. So if you want to use it as variable better rename it to something else. For starters do that or just paste correct code if you have one. There are many unknowns in what you posted that you need to clarify for someone to help you. I mean what is `client`, `gd`, `dera[['names']]`, `dropna()`?

Comment: Hey, sorry with the nomenclature of my code. I have updated it correctly now. I think now you can understand my concern.

Answer (score 0):

So let's forget about whole code before `z = del['names'].values.tolist()` and assume it works, you could change `del` name to some other name as del is a build in symbol in python. But if it works then it wokrs. 
So it seems that `z` is some list, let's say it's a list of strings then it would look like `['value1', 'value2']`. If you want to send it to your browser as is you should change it to string with `str(z)`. Perhaps you want to send some value of your list then you chould send `z[0]`. But still all of these are my quesses, you should provide exact stacktrace of your errror.

Comment: I have fixed this issue with the following df = ' '.join(dera['names']). I have passed this df to selenium send keys. It worked.